# Multiple asynchronous views

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, async-await

I'm new to asp.net mvc 4 and I have a question regarding the new async/await feature. In [this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-mvc-4), the section 'Performing Multiple Operations in Parallel' returns the 3 types of lists (Product, Gizmo and Widget) as a single view.

I'm trying to achieve the same sort of UI, except that my 3 lists would be 3 different views.
The user would type a value in a searchbox and hit the search button to trigger a call to the asynchronous controller method. But that should return 3 different views, which is I believe not possible.

Does it make sense then to have 3 partial views and to call three different async controller method? Would the views then appear on the screen as soon as the controller methods return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bundle 3 requests in 1. 
You will have to do 3 async calls (via jquery or whatever framework you are using) and then load in your 3 views.

Answer (score 0):

Async doesn't change the HTTP protocol. You get one reply for each request, and that's it.

If you want 3 different (partial) views returned independently from each other, then you'll have to make 3 requests from the client.